# Adding an image into a django template from the static folder - Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django template and I want to add a static image to the file from my static folder that I have within the application.
I am trying to but nothing is appearing on the template.

*Does anyone know where my error is coming from?*

**Here is my code:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="static/images/Artboard1.png" alt="">
    <h2>{{ currentUser.username }}</h2>
  </div>

  <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**Here is an image of my directory:**

[image]

Comment: in which python file are you trying to add it?

Comment: For a start, you need an absolute path: `/static/images/Artboard1.png`. Also how have you configured static files? Is this is dev or production?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

load *staticfiles* tag to template after *extends*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
```

and then use it in **src** attribute of *img HTML tag*

```
<img src="{% static 'images/Artboard1.png'%}" alt="">
```

Comment: @Sandeep it will work with `{%load static %}` as well.

Answer (score 7):

Configure the following setting in your setting.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_files")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

And use in your template

```
<img src="{% static 'images/Artboard1.png'%}" alt="">
```

Hope this is help you

Comment: I implimented the code that you have and got this message `Invalid block tag on line 6: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` @nikhilrane

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I sorted it out by adding `{% load static %}` to every subpage.

like here:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
{{ title }}
{% endblock title %}

{% block hero %}
<picture class="hero__background">
    <img src="{% static 'top_banner.jpg' %}" alt="" srcset="">    
</picture>
{% endblock hero %}
```