# cannot load image in html template in django application

Tags: html, django

I am trying to put an image in html template in my django applicarion but its is not displayed. When i inspect, it says image cannot be loaded.

HTML code:

```
<div class = "col-md-4">
  <img src= "/static/images/abc.jpg" alt="sorry"/>
  </div>
```

location of the image abc.png is /home/user/demo/mysite/mysite/static/images/abc.png
and my django application is bookmark which resides in mysite(demo/mysite)

Is it the correct way of giving path in a django application or something else needs to be done.

```html
.
└── mysite
    ├── bookmark
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── admin.pyc
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── forms.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
    │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20171029_1436.py
    │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20171029_1436.pyc
    │   │   ├── 0003_userbookmark.py
    │   │   ├── 0003_userbookmark.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── models.pyc
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── style.css
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── 20150225_134637.jpg
    │   │   ├── abc.jpg
    │   │   ├── base_generic.html
    │   │   ├── category.html
    │   │   ├── index.html
    │   │   ├── login.html
    │   │   ├── myprofile.html
    │   │   ├── profile.html
    │   │   ├── register2.html
    │   │   ├── register.html
    │   │   ├── registerInterest.html
    │   │   ├── sample
    │   │   └── success.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── views.pyc
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysite
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── images
    │   │       ├── abc.jpg
    │   │       └── icons_core-88916797fd4fde57d4120dea4c239f1d@1x.png
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   └── wsgi.pyc
    └── urls.py
```

I have edited the post and added the tree structure of my project

Comment: maybe a tree of your project would help..

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an image into a django template from the static folder - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602422/adding-an-image-into-a-django-template-from-the-static-folder-django)

Comment: @AaronVisang I have edited my question and added the tree structure of my project

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way to use static files in django templates

```
{% load static %}

<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src= "{% static "images/abc.jpg" %} alt="sorry"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this as well but did not work. do we need to change settings.py file as well?